# How to nicely handle cdialogex resizing?

Tags: c++, mfc, resize, cdialog

I do not want to use another classes for this purpose like easysize or sizecbar from codeproject.com. I am using MFC CDialogEx. I try this:

```
LRESULT ChildDialog::OnNcHitTest(CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    //UINT nHitTest = CWnd::OnNcHitTest(uParam, lParam);
    //return (nHitTest == HTLEFT) ? HTNONE : nHitTest;

    return CDialogEx::OnNcHitTest(point);
}

void ChildDialog::OnSizing(UINT fwSide, LPRECT pRect)
{
    //
    //TRACE("%d\n", fwSide);

    if (fwSide == WMSZ_RIGHT)
    {

        SetClassLong(m_hWnd,
            GCL_HCURSOR,
            (LONG)LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));

        //ASSERT(FALSE);
        //AfxMessageBox(_T("right"));
    }
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here

    CDialogEx::OnSizing(fwSide, pRect);


}
```

When i click on right of the dialog message show right.

As you can see in the pitcher i try to do like this. Change cursor, draw black dot lines. resize dialog only one side upper and want to disable all corner and left, right and down. And also when i resize dialog from upper side also want to move upper control.

[image]

I do not want someone do all this for me. Just advice how i can achieve this. I take this pitcher from software depends.exe. Any help will appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? You can setup the dialog resizing all within the IDE. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle  Yes i am using visual studio 2013 With MFC.

Comment: Consider trying version 2015 or 2017 as they added native support in the IDE for dialog resizing. I have now completely removed the CSizingDialog class that I used to depend on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle OnNCHitTest and OnSetCursor in order to change the cursor. Return HTNOWHERE from OnNCHitTest when the cursor is over a border and set the corresponding cursor in OnSetCurosr. You can have a member variable set from OnNCHitTest to know the hit test value, like m_hittest. 
In order to do the sizing you can use CRectTracker Class in OnMouseMove when you have the capture (left button down).